# power line from SMPS filtering for power amplifier

Tags: amplifier, filter

I am designing a power amplifier using switching mode PSU (85kHz switching frequency), and would like to hear opinions on using L-C or even R-C filters for noise line filtering and choosing f-3dB corner frequency.

Currently, the amplifier is powered from a 100V PSU and I'm using a 4uH inductor (R = 0.2 ohms), along with  6x 680uF electrolytic caps (ESR = 0.16 ohm). I do not see any difference with or without the inductor. Even without the caps, the amplifier rise time and any noise rejection on the power supply line are almost the same.

Comment: What were your test results and what are your expectations? Specs?

Comment: Do you know what the power supply rejection ratio (PSRR) is for your amplifier?

Comment: "*and would like to hear opinions*" -- best rephrase that, it's against the [rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).